# Ajax call add current url in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I am trying to perform an ajax call using jquery in wordpress js file, it automatically redirects to current path and then appends my custom path so I can't redirect my true URL.

Here is my code:

```
var path_test = document.location.hostname + '/wpcontent/themes/expression/imagecount.php';
var path;
$.ajax({
   url: path_test,
  type: "GET",
  data: '30'
 }).done(function() {
    alert('ajax call success');
});
```

It adds path, but first adds current URL then adds my URL so ajax call fails.

Comment: What event are you running this code under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any ajax calls you should refer to the codex.

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
2. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

Even though if you are not running it in a plugin.

**Server-Side**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

    // Here you would fetch and process desired file.
}
```

**Client Side**

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

In a proper setting u dont want to call files directly from your theme folder, its better to have a single access point which you can load the file u want and return a proper response.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're missing `location.protocol` (http:).
Try this:

```
var path_test = location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + '/wpcontent/themes/expression/imagecount.php';
```

Comment: @Abdul wired, I've retested it and it looks OK. What request is sent when you check the "Network Monitor" in Firefox or Chrome "Developer tools"?