# ajax call in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am new to `wordpress` and I need to make `ajax` call to fetch `json` object onchange of dropdown option in wordpress. I am not able to call `php` file present in same directory so I used `<?php echo admin_url('custom-file.php'); ?>` and placed php file in wp-admin, I am able to get the result using it but the changes are erased when I update the `wordpress` . I am confused how to call php file in same directory as that of the calling `php` file

[AJAX call in wordpress template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726684/ajax-call-in-wordpress-template)
[Ajax call add current url in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852610/ajax-call-add-current-url-in-wordpress)

I found these two links but didn't understand how does it actually work.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress is also provide ajax handling mathods and hooks. Developer can easy way to handle ajax request in plugins or theme functions.php.  
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is demo of Custom `AJAX` with WordPress..

Bellow script is HTML

```
    <div class="ajax-column">
  <div class="options">
    <select id="custom-change">
        <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
        <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
        <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
        <option value="val4">Val 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="ajax_result_form">
    <div id="ajax_text_result"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="" id="ajax_result"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is JS Script as my-ajax-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {


jQuery('#custom-change').change(function(e) {

        var text = jQuery('#custom-change').val();        
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: admin_url,
                dataType:"json",
                data: { 
                    action: 'data_custom_ajax',
                    text: text,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){                    
                    if(data['data_result']==''){
                        jQuery('#ajax_result').hide();                        
                    }
                    else{
                        jQuery('#ajax_result').css('display','block');
                        jQuery('#ajax_result').html(data['data_result']);                            
                    }
                }
        });
    });
});
```

This is WordPress script as theme's functions.php file.

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',    array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

    /* Custom Ajax */
    function data_custom_ajax(){    
        $custom_val = $_POST['text'];

        $testdomin_query = new WP_Query($testdomin_args_search);
        $testdomin_result='';   
        if(!empty($custom_val)){
            $testdomin_result = _e('Your Action hear','textdomin');
        }
        else
            $testdomin_result = _e('Not found','textdomin');

        echo json_encode(array("data_result"=>$testdomin_result));
        die;
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_custom_ajax', 'data_custom_ajax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_data_custom_ajax', 'data_custom_ajax');
```

Comment: if you getting problem i will help you.

Comment: I tried your example, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: admin_url is not defined` error.